# Directed Graphs

Tags: design, cohesion

Conisder the following piece of code :

```
cin >> a >> b;
int x,y,z;
x=0; y=1; z=1;
if (a > b){
x = a*b;
while (10 > a){
y=y+z;
a=a+5;
}
else {
x=x+b;
}
```

Its Directed graph is shown below :
[image]

Now the next figure is Annotated tokens showing the slices on which the tokens occur 
[image]

Now from the above figure we can calculate many cohesion metrics ( for example weak functional cohesion) .  My question is how did we transform the directed graph to this annotated diagram . In other words I can't understand this statement "Annotated tokens showing the slices on which the tokens occur" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the output `X` (its on the bottom). The notation states that the `X` relies only on itself. Which makes sense: `evaluate(X) == X`.

One step up and you have the statement `x = x b`. Again `evaluate(X) == X` so the `x` on the left hand side of the assignment is self-explanatory. The `x` and `b` on the right of the assignment only influence `x` though, hence they influence the output token `X`. `b` is the input token `B`, so the input token also affects the outcome of `X`.

Now the input token `B` can also influence to output token `Y`. It does this by the `(a > b)` comparison being true. This executes extra code that modifies `y`. You can see this by the arrows. So while it does not appear in the expressions concerning `y` it none the less has an effect. Similarly for `a` and the output token `A`.

What this leaves us with is each symbol being annotated with the outputs it influences.

note: I've capitalised the input/output variables to differentiate for the intermediates as lower-case.